# .sort getting value by a listener Javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting, addeventlistener

So I've come this far, been studing Javascript for around 2month so im a newbie. The problem is to sort this elements with a listener in real time.
I have this.

```
const buttonClick = document.getElementById("btn");
const showAll = document.getElementById("showAllPokemon");
const pokeDatabase = pokemon.pokemon;

const name_AZ = (a, b) => (a.name > b.name ? 1 : b.name > a.name ? -1 : 0);
const name_ZA = (a, b) => (a.name > b.name ? -1 : a.name < b.name ? 1 : 0);
const number_19 = (a, b) => (a.num > b.num ? 1 : b.num > a.num ? -1 : 0);
const number_91 = (a, b) => (a.num > b.num ? -1 : a.num < b.num ? 1 : 0);

buttonClick.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  document.getElementById("root").style.display = "none";
  showAll.style.display = "block";

  loadSelectedPokemon("all");

  document
    .getElementById("dropdownType")
    .addEventListener("change", (event) => {
      loadSelectedPokemon(event.target.value);
    });

  document.getElementById("sortBy").addEventListener("change", (event) => {
    if (event.target.value === "sort__az") {
      return (sortSelectedPokemon = name_AZ);
    } else if (event.target.value === "sort__za") {
      return (sortSelectedPokemon = name_ZA);
    } else if (event.target.value === "sort__19") {
      return (sortSelectedPokemon = number_19);
    } else if (event.target.value === "sort__91") {
      return (sortSelectedPokemon = number_91);
    }
  });

  function loadSelectedPokemon(selectedType) {
    const filterFunction = (pkm) =>
      selectedType === "all" || pkm.type.includes(selectedType);

    document.getElementById("allPokeContainer").innerHTML = "";
    pokeDatabase
      .filter(filterFunction)
      .sort(sortSelectedPokemon)
      .forEach((poke) => {
        let matchingPoke = document.createElement("div");
        matchingPoke.className = "pokeListStyle";
        matchingPoke.onclick = function () {
          pokeStats(poke);
        };
        matchingPoke.innerHTML = `<p class= "pokeNumber">${poke.num}</p>
                                  <img class="pokeImgList" src="${poke.img}">
                                  <p class= "pokeName">${poke.name}</p>`;
        document.getElementById("allPokeContainer").appendChild(matchingPoke);
      });
  }
});
```

```
 <div id="showAllPokemon" style="display: none">
      <select id="dropdownType">
        <option value="" disabled selected>-- Elemento --</option>
        <option value="all" class="typeClass">Todos</option>
        <option value="grass" class="typeClass">Planta</option>
        <option value="normal" class="typeClass">Normal</option>
        <option value="fire" class="typeClass">Fuego</option>
        <option value="water" class="typeClass">Agua</option>
        <option value="electric" class="typeClass">Eléctrico</option>
        <option value="ice" class="typeClass">Hielo</option>
        <option value="fighting" class="typeClass">Lucha</option>
        <option value="poison" class="typeClass">Veneno</option>
        <option value="ground" class="typeClass">Tierra</option>
        <option value="flying" class="typeClass">Volador</option>
        <option value="psychic" class="typeClass">Psíquico</option>
        <option value="bug" class="typeClass">Bicho</option>
        <option value="rock" class="typeClass">Roca</option>
        <option value="ghost" class="typeClass">Fantasma</option>
        <option value="dragon" class="typeClass">Dragón</option>
      </select>

      <select id="sortBy">
        <option value="" disabled selected>-- Ordenar --</option>
        <option value="sort__az">A-Z</option>
        <option value="sort__za">Z-A</option>
        <option value="sort__19">001-250</option>
        <option value="sort__91">250-001</option>
      </select>

      <div id="allPokeContainer"></div>
    </div>
```

So basically, i need to pass the functions **name_AZ** **name_ZA** **number_19** **number_9** to the sort [ex .sort(number_19)] from a dropdown select option and update the way is sort if I change them (by name asc-desc, by name desc-asc, by number both ways). It needs to be in a cascade way with the filter by type (first filter and then sort) Every else work perfectly:
-Show all poke.
-Filter by type.
-Create elements forEach.

Error log
Uncaught ReferenceError: sortSelectedPokemon is not defined at loadSelectedPokemon (main.js:42) at HTMLButtonElement. (main.js:15) The code broke and do nothing.If I put the listener outside, my const cannot reach the sort.
In one of my tries I initialice sortSelectedPokemon with one of the Functions, and it worked, but then again, the listener do nothing "on the fly", just past by and dont re-sort.

Some ideas? I tried some other ways but at this point Im starting to despair, thx in advance

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Does *anything* happen? Are errors reported? Do some sort options work but not others?

Comment: It's almost always wrong to add event listeners inside other event listeners. Every time you click on the button, you're adding another change listener to the dropdowns.

Comment: You don't need listeners on the dropdowns. `loadSelectedPokemon()` should simply get the values of the dropdowns, and use those values to filter and sort the pokemons.

Comment: @Pointy main.js:42 Uncaught ReferenceError: sortSelectedPokemon is not defined
    at loadSelectedPokemon (main.js:42)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (main.js:15)
The code broke and do nothing.

Comment: @Barmar The problem is, when do the listener outside, my const cannot reach the sort

Comment: `let selectedType = showAll.value; const filterFunction = (pkm) =>
      selectedType === "all" || pkm.type.includes(selectedType);`

Comment: Also adding event handlers inside the button "click" handler is going to cause problems. The `.addEventHandler()` method **adds** an event handler: it does not take any previously-added handlers away. Your sort method should be initialized to some default sort method before anything happens.

Comment: @Barmar The problem is not the filter, is the sort.

Comment: @Pointy Yes in one of my tries I initialice sortSelectedPokemon with one of the Functions, and it worked, but then again, the listener do nothing "on the fly", just past by and dont re-sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`loadSelectedPokemon()` can get the values of the dropdowns itself. Then you don't need `change` listeners on the dropdowns that set variables, and `loadSelectedPokemon()` can be a top-level function.

```js
const buttonClick = document.getElementById("btn");
const showAll = document.getElementById("showAllPokemon");
const pokeDatabase = pokemon.pokemon;

const name_AZ = (a, b) => (a.name > b.name ? 1 : b.name > a.name ? -1 : 0);
const name_ZA = (a, b) => (a.name > b.name ? -1 : a.name < b.name ? 1 : 0);
const number_19 = (a, b) => (a.num > b.num ? 1 : b.num > a.num ? -1 : 0);
const number_91 = (a, b) => (a.num > b.num ? -1 : a.num < b.num ? 1 : 0);

loadSelectedPokemon(); // show all Pokemon before the sort

buttonClick.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  document.getElementById("root").style.display = "none";
  showAll.style.display = "block";

  loadSelectedPokemon();
});

document.getElementById("dropdownType").addEventListener("change", loadSelectedPokemon);
showAll.addEventListener("change", loadSelectedPokemon);
document.getElementById("sortBy").addEventListener("change", loadSelectedPokemon);

function loadSelectedPokemon() {
  let selectedType = showAll.value;
  const filterFunction = (pkm) =>
    selectedType === "all" || pkm.type.includes(selectedType);

  let sortSelectedPokemon;
  switch (document.getElementById("sortBy").value) {
    case "sort__az":
      sortSelectedPokemon = name_AZ;
      break;
    case "sort__za":
      sortSelectedPokemon = name_ZA;
      break;
    case "sort__19":
      sortSelectedPokemon = sort__19;
      break;
    case "sort__91":
      sortSelectedPokemon = sort__19;
      break;
    default:
      alert("Select a sort order");
      return;
  }

  document.getElementById("allPokeContainer").innerHTML = "";
  pokeDatabase
    .filter(filterFunction)
    .sort(sortSelectedPokemon)
    .forEach((poke) => {
      let matchingPoke = document.createElement("div");
      matchingPoke.className = "pokeListStyle";
      matchingPoke.onclick = function() {
        pokeStats(poke);
      };
      matchingPoke.innerHTML = `<p class= "pokeNumber">${poke.num}</p>
                                  <img class="pokeImgList" src="${poke.img}">
                                  <p class= "pokeName">${poke.name}</p>`;
      document.getElementById("allPokeContainer").appendChild(matchingPoke);
    });
}
```

Comment: I see what you did there, the problem is: 1- The MVP of my code specifically tells me that all pokemon should be showing prior the sort. 2- The sort must be constantly changing my list of Pokemon, not only for the fist time. Thats why i thought it was best with an addEventListener("change",  ). I'll keep trying from here

Comment: You can add a `change` event listener to the dropdowns, it just calls `loadSelectedPokemon()`.

Comment: Maybe im not following you. I need for example, select Fire type, and then sort 9-1, and then if I change my sort value again dont do anything. It need to constantly arrange the list. Thx anyways for your time and ideas.

Comment: I updated the answer a few minutes ago. When you change the sort value, it sorts the list again.

Comment: `document.getElementById("sortBy").addEventListener("change", loadSelectedPokemon);`

Comment: Is not working. First popup the alert and then show blank page, even changing a reloading.

Comment: It did not work like i need it. The last update simply crash, BUT i used part of the code on my proyect so i'll accept the answer, thx for the time @Barmar